# Why do I get 500 error on Azure after using ViewBag?

Tags: c#, azure, web, .net-core, model-view-controller

I've been testing my app on localhost and it works fine. But, when I tried to deploy it after changing this code, it didn't work anymore. Azure thows me 500 error for no reason at all.

I added this base controller and each controller inherits from it:

```
    public class BaseController(IConfiguration configuration) : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration = configuration;
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_configuration["BlockPage"] == "true")
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/PageBlocked.cshtml" };
                    return;
                }
                ViewBag.PaidPage = _configuration["PaidPage"] == "true" ? true : false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

For instance:

```
public class HomeController(IWorkContainer workContainer, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IConfiguration configuration) : BaseController(configuration)
{
    private readonly IWorkContainer _workContainer = workContainer;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager = signInManager;
...
...
...
}
```

The only place I use `ViewBag` is in `_Layout.cshtml` to show the user a message:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@{
    var paidPage = ViewBag.PaidPage;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
...
...
...
```

Almost every .cshtml View uses this layout.

I suspect it comes from `ViewBag`, because after several changes, it was the only thing I removed that made the page work again.
Still don't understand why, need some explanation and if possible also a fix please!

Comment: Are you getting the error locally as well ?

Comment: What is the version of the app?

Comment: According to your scenario, the 500 error is likely not directly caused by ViewBag itself, but rather by the code within your `BaseController.OnActionExecuting`.
It seems `try...catch` block within `OnActionExecuting` catches any exceptions but then simply re-throws them. This could be masking the actual cause of the 500 error.

Comment: To get the detailed error message update the value of `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true` in the `web.config` file in the deployed files.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/pvJbka4.png)

Comment: The ViewBag value might be null.Add the code to null check the paidPage value.

Comment: Cany you please share the code repo if possible ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error happens in the view, the value of `ViewBag.PaidPage` is null, so that's why the app crashes. The error might not be because of the ViewBag itself, but rather for the data passed from the controller. Here's the link to the repo: https://github.com/MartinSola55/Aguas-Nico-Net-Core.
You'll see that I harcoded the value so that the app can work properly. The commit is this `c4c60b43e0da576b3732a31326a0752fcaee8acd`.
BTW i'm using .NET 8, and no, I'm not getting the error locally.